# How to reinstall the driver after replacing the CPU and motherboard in Debian11?

Tags: debian

My English is not very good, but I added a picture description.

As the title goes, when I started, he prompted many driver errors. I solved them through apt install intel-microcode, but if I didn't do so, how should I ask computer to re identify the new driver from the installation source file and install the overlay? I searched the Internet for a long time and couldn't find the relevant technical support.[image]

Comment: what driver? what errors?   This question is far too vague to even attempt to answer, and is probably why your searches found no solution.  BTW, there is no `intel-microcoapt` package - do you mean `intel-microcode`?  and who is "he" / "him" ? are you referring to another person? or is this some weird gendered way of referring to the computer or the installer software?

Comment: Sorry, I modified some typos and uploaded additional pictures. I don't know how to describe the errors in the picture. I just replaced the CPU and motherboard for my computer, which caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a kernel package is installed, a custom initramfs file (named in Debian as `/boot/initrd.img-<kernel_version>` for legacy reasons) is generated. The initramfs generator (`update-initramfs`) attempts to keep the size of the initramfs file small, by including only what is needed by the *current* system *at the time the initramfs creator is executed*: it obviously cannot predict any future hardware changes.

More specifically, the initramfs generator adds only the microcode for your *current* processor into initramfs for the *early microcode update system*. After changing the hardware, you should rebuild your initramfs files with `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`: the initramfs generator will then review the kernel modules and firmware/microcode files required by your new hardware, and will rebuild the initramfs files accordingly.

Removing and reinstalling (or updating) the `intel-microcode` package will also trigger `update-initramfs` as a post-install action, so that explains why `apt install intel-microcode` fixed your issue.

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please update microcode to version 0xb2 (or later)
```

This message refers to Time Stamp Counter, which is part of the processor (CPU). Generally, the word "microcode" is used with the processor only.

```
x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
```

This is just a warning that the processor's Virtual Machine support extensions have been disabled by the system BIOS. If you want to run KVM, VirtualBox, VMware Workstation or similar, you might need to change a BIOS setting to enable VMX first.

```
i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: failed to load i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (-2)
firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
```

This is a message about missing firmware for Intel Skylake-family iGPU. Since the `i915` driver is also responsible for the framebuffer console display, it is loaded very early at boot. It makes the graphical `plymouth` boot splash screen possible.

Debian kernels are even patched to give you a direct link to a relevant page of Debian Wiki. There, the paragraph "Firmware after installation" is the one relevant to you. It tells you how to find the missing firmware and install it **and then update the initramfs**, and gives an example:

```
$ apt-file search skl_guc_62.0.0.bin
firmware-misc-nonfree: /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_62.0.0.bin
$ sudo apt install firmware-misc-nonfree
$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

It seems like in your "searching the Internet for a long time", you missed the most obvious spot.

The `ACPI Error` messages seem to be about poorly-programmed Windows Management Instrumentation interfaces (WMI) in your system's ACPI firmware. These are often harmless, and only a BIOS update can fix them.